# Latex command inside metapost label

Tags: luatex, metapost, luamplib

This is a minimal code example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
label(btex A-\textbf{B} etex,origin);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The compilation with lualatex (version 1.10.0) produces this result.

[image]

Comment: Sorry to ask, what is your question?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I guess the question is how to use `\textbf` correctly inside of `mplibcode`.

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting the result A-B with a bold style B.

Comment: This is a bug. You should report it: https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. If I run your code in TeX Live 2015 I get the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Bug reported: https://github.com/lualatex/luamplib/issues/86.